# In Unreal Engine editor, how to specify paths relative to the project folder root?

Tags: environment-variables, unreal-engine4

For a casual search in UE's docs I couldn't find environment variables that I could use in the settings within the Editor UI and would look like $PROJECT_ROOT. And my specified relative paths like `path/to/my/subfolder` seem to get resolved as relative to where the installed Unreal Engine is.

How should I specify the project root to be used by all relative paths filled in the project settings without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself after some research.

For my purposes, i.e., filling forms in the Editor, the realistic solution is to run Editor script such as via [the Python Editor Script plugin](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/PythonAPI/index.html), where you could query the project data using [unreal.GeneralProjectSettings](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/PythonAPI/class/GeneralProjectSettings.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's no environmental variable. This is how to obtain the relative/full path of the project directory:

```
FString RelativePath = FPaths::GameContentDir();

FString FullPath = IFileManager::Get().ConvertToAbsolutePathForExternalAppForRead(*RelativePath);
```

[source](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/580005/getting-full-path-of-project-directory.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I know that I could do this in runtime code, but as my title says, what I need is to specify paths in the Editor UI, such as within Project Settings, Editor Settings, etc.